# Automating Google sheet

Tags: database, google-apps-script, automation

I have 2 sheets: Sheet1 and Sheet2

Sheet1 is connected through Google app script and takes monthly data from user, this data is editable

I want to create a history of the data entered by user in Sheet2
Once the current month is over the data entered in Sheet2 will copied and the data in Sheet1 will be deleted to facilitate entry of new data.
Thus creating a history of month on month data in Sheet2.

I am very new to google scipt and have no idea where to start from any guidanace and help will be much appricated.

I have connected the sheet 1 through app sheet successfully that allows the user to entry the data in sheet 1 by using the app.

Comment: May I just clarify. You have one spreadsheet containing two sheets. User data is input each month into "Sheet 1" (spelling??) whether manually or by a script/function. "Sheet 2" (spelling??) is an archive of "Sheet 1" data. At the end of each month, you want to run a script  to do two things: 1) copy the data from "Sheet 1" to "Sheet 2" (updating the archive) and 2) delete the data from "Sheet 1" so it is ready for the new month. Is that correct?

Comment: @Tedinoz yes you are correct. But the 2 sheets:Sheet1 and Sheet2 are not in one spreadsheet, they are 2 different spreadsheets. Rest everything is as you have understood.

Answer (score 0):

You want to archive data from one spreadsheet to another, then delete the content from the original spreadsheet.

This answer describes the main steps that have to be taken. All ranges are created dynamically - so the script will be valid regardless of the size of the data, or the size of the existing archive.

Copy the following script into the project Editor of the "archive" spreadsheet. Several `Logger.log` statements have been left in the script to assist the OP in understanding the effect of code.

**Step#1 - get the data**

- open the "Sheet1" spreadsheet
- get the data

  - used `getDataRange()` to get the data because you don't have to worry about the number of rows, etc
  - `getDataRange()` will include any header row, so used `splice(0, 1)` to delete the first element (the headers) of the data array.

**Step#2 - define the Archive range**

- very common, "normal" commands.

**Step#3 - copy the data to the archive**

- `targetRange.setValues(data)`: a simple `setValues()` - remember `data` doesn't include a header row.

**Step#4 - clear the content from Sheet1**

- `var sourceRange = sheet1.getRange(2,1,data.length,lc)` - define the range; note starting in row#2 (*after* the header row)
- `sourceRange.clearContent()`

---

```
/*
// this function copies user data from "Sheet1" 
// archives it on this spreadsheet
// then clears the content from Sheet1
//
// this function is bound to the archive spreadsheet
*/

function dataArchive() {
  // open Sheet1
  var sheetID = "14XJEmCw57n4W0ciFKFnme6ml20P-JgMd82LsgrKcQCE"
  var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetID)  
  var dataSheetName = "Sheet1"
  var sheet1 = datasheet.getSheetByName(dataSheetName)
  var data = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues()
  // Logger.log(data) // DEBUG
  data.splice(0, 1)
  // Logger.log(data) // DEBUG

  // get the target range for the current sheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var archiveSheetName = "Sheet2"
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName(archiveSheetName)
  var lr = sheet2.getLastRow()
  var lc = sheet2.getLastColumn()
  var targetRange = sheet2.getRange(+lr+1,1,data.length,lc)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: target range: "+targetRange.getA1Notation())

  // copy the data from sheet1 to sheet 2
  targetRange.setValues(data)

  // delete the data from Sheet 1
  var sourceRange = sheet1.getRange(2,1,data.length,lc)
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: source data range: "+sourceRange.getA1Notation())
  sourceRange.clearContent()
}
```

---